# Wordpress - Display MySQL Column Data on Product Page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Dears,

I've created a python script that exports data from MSSQL and imports into the MySQL database. Everything works smoothly.

Now I want to display the new column data which I've added... but I don't have any PHP skills.

The data is in the `wc_product_meta_lookup` table. The column name is `dLieferdatum`.

I guess it might start with something like:

```
global $product;

$results = $product->get_col( "
    SELECT dLieferdatum
    FROM jll99_wc_product_meta_lookup
    WHERE dLieferdatum IS NOT NULL
" );
```

I would highly appreciate any idea :-)

Further note: I built a function that displays if an item is available or not available. I want to display the data from `dLieferdatum` instead of "bestellbar" if `dLieferdatum is not NULL`

```
function show_stock() {
    global $product;
        // if manage stock is enabled

        if ( $product->stock ) {  

            // if stock is low
            if ( number_format($product->stock,0,'','') > 0 && number_format($product->stock,0,'','') < 7) { 
                echo '<div class="less-available"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> auf Lager</div>';
                echo '<div class="ind_individual-delivery-time">Zustellung in 1 - 3 Werktagen</div>'; 
            }        

            // if more than 6 are available
            if ( number_format($product->stock,0,'','') > 0 && number_format($product->stock,0,'','') > 6) { 
                echo '<div class="available"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> auf Lager</div>'; 
                echo '<div class="ind_individual-delivery-time">Zustellung in 1 - 3 Werktagen</div>'; 
            }
        }

        if ( $product->managing_stock() && number_format($product->stock,0,'','') < 1) {
            echo '<div class="backorder_item"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> bestellbar</div>';            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similiar problem and it got just solved.

First you have to create a function to `SELECT` the data from the database:

```
function get_product_meta_dLieferdatum( $product_id ) {
            global $wpdb;
            return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT dLieferdatum
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_product_meta_lookup
                WHERE product_id = '%d' AND dLieferdatum <> '0000-00-00'
            ", $product_id ) );
        }
```

The second step is to call the return value of the function in your "show_stock()" function. So you need to place below code - for example - in front of the `if` call

```
$dLieferdatum = get_product_meta_dLieferdatum( $product->get_id() );
```

Now `$dLieferdatum` has the value you wanted. At last you can just display the data with a simple `echo` or `print`:

```
echo $dLieferdatum;
```